# How to perform nodeJS integration tests with Jasmine?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, automated-tests

I have a server app written in nodeJS that serve as a REST Api. For unit testing I use Jasmine and I would like to perform some integration tests as well with some mock data. Tests like this one:

import ApiTestClient from "../support/api-test-client";

```
import User from "../../src/model/user";

describe("GET /users", () => {

    it("returns an array with all users", done => {
        ApiTestClient
            .getUsers()
            .then(users => {
                expect(users).toEqual(jasmine.any(Array));
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => fail(err));
    });

});
```

With normal unit tests I simply can mock the API calls but in this case I must first run the server app, opening 2 terminals, one for `npm start` and then another for `npm test`.

So far I've tried adding this pretest script to the `package.json`:

```
"pretest": "node dist/src/server.js &"
```

So the process runs in the background, but it doesn't feel right since it will be running after the test suite ends.

How can I start/stop the server application automatically in order to run this integration tests?

Comment: Do you use any framework to serve the the REST requests?
Wouln't it be possible to serve the requests with the same node instance that is running the tests?

Comment: Thanks @fonkap, I am using Express for the server-app and Jasmine for the tests, no other framework involved. What you are you exactly suggesting?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was a little busy, but finaly I got some time to write a running example, I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy way to do it using `beforeEach` to start `express` before the suite.

note: This was tested on `jasmine 2.6.0` and `express 4.15.3`

Minimal example:

```
//server.js 
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/world', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/moon', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello Moon!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})



//spec/HelloSpec.js
var request = require("request");

describe("GET /world", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    //we start express app here
    require("../server.js");
  });


  //note 'done' callback, needed as request is asynchronous
  it("returns Hello World!", function(done) {
    request("http://localhost:3000/world", function(error, response, html){
      expect(html).toBe("Hello World!");
      done();
    });
  });

  it("returns 404", function(done) {
    request("http://localhost:3000/mars", function(error, response, html){
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(404);
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

After running it with `jasmine` command it returns the expected:

```
Started
Example app listening on port 3000!
..


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.129 seconds
```

And server is closed (and port 3000 is closed also)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does this mean the server is starting/stopping during every test?

Comment: It works like a charm, many thanks. I put it inside the beforeAll method and also removed the `.js` extension since I use TS

Comment: I am happy to hear! And no, it isn't, it starts and stops only once for all the suite. That's why I wrote two tests.

Comment: What closes the server here?

Comment: The server runs in the same node process that does the testing, hence when this process ends the server is closed. I hope I am not missing anything here, but is easy to check that the server is actually closing.